# upload image to a cell from image picker

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I call to an image picker when a cell is tapped in a collection view:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 2:
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Then I want to upload an image to my cell's imageView:

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
    })
    //imageView.image = image   ---> need imageview in a cell wit indexpath = 2
}
```

How do I implement the delegates and protocols?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

Option #1

```
 arr[2] = image
 let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at:IndexPath(row:2,section:0)) as! cellName 
 cell.imageView.image = image
```

Option #2 ( Recommended ) as it's a bad idea to access the cell out of table

is to edit the image in model , then reload the table/indexPath

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
  arr[2] = image
  let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0) 
  self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

Plus `cellForItemAt` should have

```
let cell = ///
cell.imageView.image = arr[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Option 1 is a bad idea because the image goes away when the table is scrolled due to cell reuse. Worse, the image might end up on the wrong row when scrolling, depending on how `cellForItemAt` is implemented.

Comment: @rmaddy no , since the op presents the picker from the cell , then it's visible so we'll never get nil , plus i edited the model with it

Comment: I didn't say anything about the cell being nil. As you know, cells get reused. If you update a cell but not the data model, things go wrong as the table is scrolled. That's the problem with option 1. That's why option 2 is much, much better.

Answer (score 0):

In the image picker delegate, you need to update the data model used to populate your collection view. Then you tell the collection view to reload that associated row.

This assumes of course that your `cellForItemAt` is written to set the cell's image appropriately from the data model.